# IE 8 not pushing footer down when jquery toggle method called

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, footer

Just getting into jquery.

This problem only occurs in IE 8, its fine in IE 7, IE 8 Compat mode, Chrome and FF.

When the nail enhancements button is clicked the content bombs over the top of the footer.

Does any body have any ideas please?  here's the page.  http://deansmith.me.uk/acrylicwizarddev/pricelist.aspx

thanks

Dean

Comment: URL returns a 404, and without any example HTML in the question, this question and answer combination is effectively useless for anyone visiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `#page`, instead of using `display: inline-block`, use `overflow: hidden`. It will clear the `float`s and fix the bug.

Comment: GREAT! Many thanks for the very quick response and successful answer.  You answered so quickly I must have made a very common CSS error.

Comment: I don't think it's that common - I just happened to have an IE open :P `display: inline-block` is rather quirky in most browsers, so using the better supported `overflow` property is recommended.

Comment: I'll keep overflow in mind.  It looks to be something i'll use again.  Thanks again.